# Type-аргументы в lambda-выражении

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Имеем следующий код внутри класса MyClass:

```
private static Comparator<Map.Entry<?, ?>> comparator = MyClass::compare;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <K,V> int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> me1, Map.Entry<K, V> me2) {
    int f = ((Comparable<K>)me1.getKey()).compareTo(me2.getKey());
    if (f!=0) return f;
    return ((Comparable<V>)me1.getValue()).compareTo(me2.getValue());
}
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как то избежать прописывания метода `compare(me1,me2)` как метода класса `MyClass` так, чтобы иметь что то в следующем роде:

```
private static Comparator<Map.Entry<?,?>> comparator = (K,V,me1,me2) -> {...};
```

Было бы здорово заменить токены `?` и `?` в этой строке на `K` и `V`, которые были бы, к примеру, при классе `MyClass<K,V>`, но non-статическое обращение, разумеется, недоступно. Мне важно оставить поле `comparator` статическим.

Comment: У функционального интерфейса Comparator метод compare принимает только 2 аргумента. для 4-х аргументов нужно объявлять свой Comparator, и свою Map.Entry, которая будет его наследовать.

Comment: Не понимаю. Я же в коде выше присвоил ссылке на компаратор метод с 2-мя ссылочными и 2-мя type-аргументами. Comparator здесь java.util.Comparator, тот самый, с "двумя аргументами". Код рабочий.

Comment: Эти токены K,V существуют только на этапе компиляции, а в лямбда-выражении me1 и me2 это конкретные агрументы для метода compare()

Comment: https://pastebin.com/P3XyFv9v кстати, всё работает и без K,V,?

Comment: Во-первых, Вы явно не поняли мой вопрос. Во-вторых, прошу не кидаться ссылками на код, который, не решая проблему, при том, содержит страшные strem'ы всякие. Я новичок, что думаю ясно из вопроса. В-третьих, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Герберт Шилдт, "Java 8. Полное руководство. Девятое издание." (стр. 446):

> **Обобщённые функциональные интерфейсы.**
>
> Указывать параметры типа в самом лямбда-выражении нельзя.
>   Следовательно, *лямбда-выражение не может быть обобщенным*.

Значит, без non-статического обращение к type-параметрам класса, содержащего поле `comparator`, или без явного прописывания метода `compare(me1, me2)` **нельзя** создать реализацию желаемого компаратора (который имел бы обобщённый метод `compare(...)`).